# Jenkins to run 10 jobs sequestially and few parallely and only run jobs what I choose

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-workflow

Jenkins to run 10 jobs sequentially and few parallely and let say 1-2 jobs are successful and job3 failed. I fixed the job3.Now I want to again trigger the job but only want to trigger it from job3.All 10 jobs have string parameter.
I can pick an choose what jobs to trigger. how can I achieve it.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of CI is to have multiple runs frequently, so that in next run you can see them all stable. Not sure why you wanted to do this. However, You can take 2 approaches.

1. You can use conditional Step plugin along with multiphase plugin,
   wrap you build step with condition and pass whether you want to run
   it or not. only if the condition is passed then the individual jobs
   will be triggered.
2. You can use jenkins-cli and trigger the jobs
       which ever you wish.